# Excel copy x amount of columns below one cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am dealing with a changing file and I would like to copy the last 10 rows of a certain column and then paste it into another worksheet, the original worksheet gets updated throughout the day.

Comment: And the question is....?

Comment: Sub newst()
Sheets("old").Select
columna = "G2"
Range(columna).Activate
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Activate


For I = 1 To 10

    Selection.Offset(-10 + I, 0).Copy
    Sheets("new").Range("A2").Offset(I, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Answer (score 0):

```
Const COLUMN_INDEX = 1 ' Desired column

Sub CopyValues()
    Dim LastRow = [A65536].End(xlUp).Row ' Find the last row index
    Dim I
    For I = LastRow - 10 To LastRow
        'Do something with Cells(I, COLUMN_INDEX).Value
    Next I
End Sub
```